# Running raml2html inside an ANT script

Tags: html, ant, build, raml

I have some RAML files sitting in a folder, and I'm setting up an ANT script to "build" them into HTML documentation using the [raml2html](https://github.com/kevinrenskers/raml2html) package featured on the [raml.org](http://raml.org/) site.
I'm new to ANT, so I'm probably not making the most efficient use of it, but that is of secondary concern.  I use two targets to accomplish this goal, and they look like this (I've ommitted clean and init):

```
<!-- Look for the RAML, send them one at a time to post-build -->

<target name="build" depends="clean, init">
    <echo message="searching for raml source in ${src}"/>
    <foreach param="file" target="post-build">
        <fileset dir="${src}">
            <include name="**/*.raml"/>
        </fileset>
    </foreach>      
</target>


<!-- Run raml2html on each of them, saving output in build/ -->
<target name="post-build" depends="">
    <echo>file: ${file}</echo>
    <substring text="${file}" parent-dir="${src}/" property="filename" />
    <echo>filename: ${filename}</echo>
    <echo>build-to: ${build}/${filename}</echo>
    <exec executable="raml2html" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-i ${file}" />
        <arg value="-o ${build}/${filename}" /> 
    </exec>
</target>
```

When I  run the ANT script: `$ant build`, those two targets return this:

```
build:
     [echo] searching for raml source in /home/ryan/workspace/RAMLValidator/src
  [foreach] The nested fileset element is deprectated, use a nested path instead

post-build:
     [echo] file: /home/ryan/workspace/RAMLValidator/src/sample.raml
     [echo] filename: sample.html
     [echo] build-to: /home/ryan/workspace/RAMLValidator/build/sample.html
     [exec] 2.0.2
```

It appears as though the arguments  I supplied to the `<exec>` translated into raml2html's `-V` option somewhere along the way, as its version is 2.0.2 when I run `$raml2html -V` from the terminal.
When I run this same command explicitly from the terminal: `$raml2html -i src/sample.raml -o build/sample.html`, it generates the HTML exactly as expected... How did I mess this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ANT treats the option flag and the flag's argument as separate entities, each needing their own `<arg />` tag in order to function properly.

Modifying the `exec` task in the "post-build" target like so fixed the problem:

```
<exec executable="raml2html" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-o" />
    <arg value="${build}/${filename}"/>
    <arg value="${file}" /> 
</exec>
```

Hopefully that saves someone a fraction of the time it cost me!